# Typeset the wildcard operator table

Tags: tables

I just want to typeset the [wildcard operator table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#ssequerybasics_topic2) at about 2/3 down the page.

[image]

I have been working forever, it doesn't even have to look nice. What tool should I be using??

My work in progress

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{|l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Wild-card Operators} \\ \hline
Character & Function \\ \hline

\_ (underscore) & matches any single character \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ \_am Frenc\_ matches Sam French, Tam Frenck, and Lam Frencq}         \\     \hline

\% & matches a string of one or more characters \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{WHERE FirstName LIKE J\% matches any name starting with J} \\ \hline

$[]$  and \^ & Matches any char in specified range, \^ is negation op \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{[a-g],[\^a-g],[bcdrf]} \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted the question if I hadn't been working on it for a considerable amount of time.

Comment: @SamFrench Your question is good and shows you've done research on it: indeed it has (up to now) 6 upvotes. The advice about looking at the starter guide is generic and doesn't mean you did wrong with your question. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility: I used the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to have better looking tables (no vertical rules), and the [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package to avoid manually computing the width for the second column; I also used a monospaced font (through `\ttfamily` and `\texttt{}`) for the code parts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{>{\ttfamily}lX}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Wild-card Operators} \\ 
\midrule
\rmfamily Character & Function \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\_ \rmfamily(underscore) 
  & matches any single character  \texttt{_am Frenc_} matches \texttt{Sam French}, \texttt{Tam Frenck}, and \texttt{Lam Frencq}  \\     
\% 
  & matches a string of one or more characters WHERE FirstName LIKE \texttt{J\%} matches any name starting with \texttt{J} \\
{[]}  \textrm{and} \^ & Matches any char in specified range, \texttt{\^} is negation op \texttt{[a-g]},\texttt{[\^{}a-g]},\texttt{[bcdrf]} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: made a few minor changes, but it looks great.

I plan to review your work at a later date. Thanks.